# How can I use MP4Box to create TS mpeg dash

Tags: video-streaming, mp4, mpeg-dash, mp4box

I'm trying to create mpeg dash files with the TS profile using MP4Box. I tried the following command:

```
MP4Box -dash 4000 -profile urn:mpeg:dash:profile:mp2t-simple:2011 -segment-name segment_ output.mp4
```

It results in a full profile as checked in the manifest file. Does MP4Box supports TS segment creation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GPAC maintainer here. Yes MP4Box supports TS segment creation. You need to provide a TS from the command-line. You can create a TS from a MP4 using the GPAC MP42TS tool.

In the future please consider using the official GPAC tracker to ask you question: https://github.com/gpac/gpac/issues. You'll benefit from answers and support from the GPAC community!